# jQuery custom events

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a Wizard control using JQuery.
I need a custom event when the user click on the next button to navigate the next wizard page.
I want to validate the forms value of the current wizard page and if it is invalid the result of the event will be false and the wizard control doesn't step to the next wizard page.

```
$.fn.wizard = function (options) {
    init(this);

    var isValid = false;

    $(this).on("tabchanging", tabchangingHandler);

    function tabchangingHandler(event) {

                    //validate controls
        return false;
    }
} 

//in the wizard page function I fire the tab changing event and I would like to catch       //the result value but how?

$(e.target).parents(".wizard-frame").trigger('tabchanging', e);
```

It seems to be very easy but I cannot catch the return value.

Comment: can't you just have your moveToNextPage logic directly in your tabchangingHandler instead of based on it's return value?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to hook `tabchangingHandler` before defining it, you are registering an `undefined` value to handle the event. You have at least two options:

- Define the function prior using it:

  ```
  function tabchangingHandler (event) {
      return false;
  }

  $(this).on("tabchanging",tabchangingHandler)
  ```
- Use an anonymous function to register the event and define the function somewhere else in the future but the same scope:

  ```
  $(this).on("tabchanging",function(e){
      tabchangingHandler(e);
  });

  function tabchangingHandler (event) {
      return false;
  }
  ```